# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) for Azure Kusto query in python

Tags: python, json, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to read the table using Azure kusto query however getting this error of decode error. After referring already available options, i have also used ".decode("utf-8")" at the end of response. But the database and query are already a string type functions so need to convert it again.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxjNY.png)

Comment: That's a `JSONDecodeError`, so checking for unicode weirdness was a good step, but what I'd really want you to check is that the string causing the error is valid JSON. I know there are a few online places that can validate JSON for you if you don't want to post the data publicly.

Answer (score 2):

There needs a slight correction in Kusto_cluster string name and the issue gets resolved. Instead of above query for Kusto_cluster, I have used https://<"clustername">.kusto.windows.net and rest of code is same.